# Show Formula Field Changes in Edit Form

Tags: formula-field, dynamic

My system setup involves Opportunities having an extra "Billing Contact" field, and when Sales Reps change this field, I want to be able for them to see, on the Opportunity Edit form/page, a property of that "Billing Contact" so that they can verify that they have chosen correctly.

And I want to do this *before* they save. I have a formula field which will show it after they save, but that creates really clunky UI.

Is there any hope for me?

Comment: I am totally down for using VisualForce, but I really don't understand how to use VisualForce to edit only a small portion of a form.  Really VisualForce is pretty confusing at this point, I don't yet have enough understanding to modify the examples in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Im afraid this wont be possible with native SF.  You could accomplish this with a VF page, but I'm assuming you are asking if it can be done with the standard pages.

Sorry its not better news.

> **EDIT**

Here are a few good places to get started if you are interested in learning more about Visualforce

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index.htm

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_workbook
Try the VF workbook here, great hands on tutorials are great

Comment: VF would be cool, but I don't really know how to approach it.  I am willing to learn, but struggling to

Comment: Added a few sources that might be a good start for you.  Start with those and post any questions you run into back here and you have lots of great people ready to help.  Good Luck  :)